# Java Performance: multiple array vs single array of custom object

Tags: java, arrays, performance

What's the best performance of these two different code solution:

```
class Meme {
  private int[] a = new int[100];
  private int[] b = new int[100];
  private int[] c = new int[100];
}
```

vs

```
class Meme {
   private MemeProp[] prop = new MemeProp[100];
   class MemeProp {
     int a;
     int b;
     int c;
   }
}
```

consider in continuous access for read and write properties `a`, `b`, `c`

I need to write code for fast execution not for memory optimization. Therefore, my performance benchmark is execution time

Comment: You could write a couple tests and time them yourself ...

Comment: Almost any time you try to outguess how the compiler is going to optimize things you're going to be wrong. This is *especially* true for a JIT compiled language like Java.

Comment: The first will almost certainly be faster. This is true even in a low-level language like C++ with unboxed objects; it'll be yet more significant with boxed ones.

Comment: Also, use C if you care about speed that much.

Comment: In what world is this *opinion-based*?

Answer (score 7):

It depends a lot on your memory access patterns.

*The first one is definitely more compact.*

User-defined types in Java carry some overhead, something like a pointer overhead per object (8 bytes on 64-bit). An `Integer` can take 16 bytes (8 bytes for `object` + 4 bytes for `int` + 4 for alignment), e.g., while an `int` takes a mere 4 bytes. It's analogous to a `class` with virtual functions in C++ storing a `vptr`.

Given this, if we look at the memory usage of `MemeProp`, we have something like this:

```
  class MemeProp {
     // invisible 8 byte pointer with 8-byte alignment requirements
     int a; // 4 bytes
     int b; // 4 bytes
     int c; // 4 bytes
     // 4 bytes of padding for alignment of invisible field
   }
```

The resulting memory size is 24 bytes per `MemeProp` instance. When we take a hundred of those, we end up with a total memory usage of 2400 bytes.

Meanwhile, your 3 arrays each containing a hundred `ints` will only require slightly over 1200 bytes (a little teeny bit extra for array overhead storing a length and pointer). That's very close to half the size of your second version.

**Sequential Access**

When you process data sequentially, speed and size often tend to go hand-in-hand. If more data can fit into a page and cache line, your code will typically consume it much faster in cases where the machine instructions don't vary much between the larger vs. tighter representation.

So from a sequential access standpoint, your first version which requires half the memory is likely to go quite a bit faster (maybe almost twice as fast in some cases).

**Random Access**

Yet random access is a different case. Let's say `a`, `b`, and `c` are equally hot fields, always accessed together in your tight loops which have a random access pattern into this structure.

In that case, your second version may actually fare better. It's because it offers a contiguous layout for a `MemeProp` object where `a`, `b`, and `c` will end up being right next to each other in memory, always (no matter how the garbage collector ends up rearranging the memory layout for a `MemeProp` instance).

With your first version, your `a`, `b`, and `c` arrays are spread out in memory. The stride between them can never be smaller than 400 bytes. This equates to potentially a lot more cache misses if you end up accessing some random element, say the 66th element, when we access `a[65]`, `b[65]`, and `c[65]`. If that's the first time we're accessing those fields, we'll end up with 3 cache misses. Then we might access `a[7]`, `b[7]`, and `c[7]`, and those would all relatively be 228 bytes apart from `a[65]`, `b[65]`, and `c[65]`, and we might end up with 3 more cache misses.

**Possibly Better than Both**

Let's say you need random AoS-style access and all fields are always accessed together. In that case, the most optimal representation will likely be this:

```
class Meme {
    private int[] abc = new int[100 * 3];
}
```

This ends up taking the minimum amount of memory of all three solutions and guarantees that `abc` fields for a single `MemeProp` are right next to each other.

Of course, there might be some cases where your mileage may vary, but this might be the strongest candidate among these three if you need both random and sequential access.

**Hot/Cold Field Splitting**

For completeness, let's consider a case where your memory access patterns are sequential but not all fields (`a/b/c`) are accessed together. Instead, you have one performance-critical loop which accesses `a` and `b` together, and some non-performance-critical code which accesses only `c`. In that case, you might get the best results from a representation like this:

```
class Meme {
    private int[] ab = new int[100 * 2];
    private int[] c = new int[100];
}
```

This makes it so our data looks like this:

```
abababab...
ccccc...
```

... as opposed to this:

```
abcabcabcabc...
```

In this case, by hoisting out `c` and putting it into a separate array, it is no longer interleaved with `a` and `b` fields, allowing the computer to "consume" this relevant data (`a` and `b` in those performance-critical loops) at a faster rate as it's moving contiguous chunks of this memory into faster but smaller forms of memory (physically-mapped page, CPU cache line).

**SoA Access Pattern**

Finally, let's say you are accessing all fields separately. Each critical loop only accesses `a`, only accesses `b`, or only accesses `c`. In that case, your first representation is likely to be the fastest, especially if your compiler can emit efficient SIMD instructions which can vectorize processing of multiple such fields in parallel.

**Relevant Data in Cache Lines**

If you find all of this confusing, I don't blame you, but there was something `harold`, a computer architecture wizard, told me once on this site. He summed it all up in the most elegant way that the goal should be to avoid loading *irrelevant* data in a cache line which is only going to be loaded and evicted without being used. As much as I had developed some intuition of that over all my profiling sessions, I never found such a concise and elegant way to put it that made sense of all those cache misses.

Our hardware and operating systems want to move memory from bigger but slower forms of memory to smaller but faster forms of memory. When it does that, it tends to "grab memory by the handful". Well, if you are trying to grab M&Ms by the handful from a bowl but you're only interested in eating green M&Ms, it becomes very inefficient to grab a handful of mixed M&Ms only to pick out the green ones and then return all the other ones to the bowl. It becomes so much more efficient in that case if you had a bowl filled with only green M&Ms, and that's kind of the goal when you are trying to settle on an efficient memory layout if I use a very crude but hopefully helpful analogy. If all you want to access in a critical loop are the analogical green M&Ms, don't mix them up (interleave that data) with red ones, blue ones, yellow ones, etc. Instead keep all those green ones right next to each other in memory so that when you grab things by the handful, you're only getting what you want.

**Data-Oriented Design**

One of the things you are doing correctly if you anticipate a large input, loopy scenario for these `MemeProps` is designing your outer, public interface at the collection level, at the `Meme` level and turning `MemeProp` fields into a private detail.

That's probably the most effective strategy before you measure is identifying the places where you process data in bulk (though `100` isn't exactly bulk, I'm hoping your actual scenario is much bigger), and designing your public interfaces accordingly.

For example, if you are designing an `Image` class and performance is a key goal, then you want to avoid exposing a `Pixel` object which provides operations on a pixel-by-pixel basis. Far better is designing this interface at the bulk `Image` or `Scanline` level, allowing a bunch of pixels to be processed in bulk.

That leaves you a lot more wiggle room to measure and tune data representations than a design which has ten thousand client dependencies to some granular `Pixel` object interface which represents a single pixel, e.g.

So anyway, safest bet is to measure, but it's good that you are designing at an appropriately-coarse level for your interface designs.

Comment: "It's even slightly better for sequential access than your first version if `a`, `b`, and `c` are always accessed together." → This surprisingly isn't actually true (at least in C++), since the pre-fetcher seems to work better on parallel streams. [See "Compact AOS vs SOA" on this slideshow.](https://github.com/joaquintides/usingstdcpp2015/blob/master/Mind%20the%20cache.pdf) The comment about random access, though, is valid, albeit only to a small degree and not at these array lengths. (Random accesses into a cold cache are a different story.)

Comment: @Veedrac Ah yeah, though I've never seen compilers actually optimize towards SoA-style SIMD intrinsics if the memory access patterns are AoS-like. That is to say, I'd expect the `a/b/c` parallel array version to be faster if there were actually three loops for each individual component (`a/b/c ` not accessed together in one loop, but accessed individually in three separate loops for vertical vectorization). I'll try to update the answer, nevertheless, to include SoA optimizations (but generally I think you have to have a vertical rather than horizontal access pattern to benefit from it).

Comment: In your "possible better than both" case, what about the extra time needed to compute index values, i.e., instead of a[i], b[i], c[i], instead you need abc[3*i], abc[3*i+1], abc[3*i+2]? Won't this be much slower?

Comment: @WillKanga That gets extremely elaborate and architecture-specific but integer multiplies tend to be very fast (compared to division which tends to be extremely slow), and sequential access patterns will generally translate to additions rather than multiply instructions. This is just crude advice with exceptions but never prioritize the cost of arithmetic over memory access.